# Find a basis for the orthogonal complement of the plane $2x + 3y + 4z = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the orthogonal complement of the plane $2x + 3y + 4z = 0$.

I am very confused on how to solve this problem, I know what orthogonal complement and a basis are but I don't understand how to represent the plane as a matrix.
I know there is an easy way of doing this with the fundamental theorem of linear algebra but I want to learn how to do it the long way and how to think through the problem. How do I get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The orthogonal complement of a subspace $U$ is the collection of all vectors $v$ such that $v\cdot u=0$ for all $u\in U$. Let $v$ be a vector in the orthogonal complement, given by $(a,b,c)$. Let $u$ be a vector in the plane given by $(x,y,z)$. Then $v\cdot u=0$, or $ax+by+cz=0$. What values could $a$, $b$, and $c$ have?

Comment: $[2, 3, 4]$, the orthogonal complement is similar to saying the nullspace of the plane, so the $x$, $y$, and $z$ values that make that equation $0$ are vectors in the plane?

Comment: Yes, and the orthogonal complement is the span of $(2,3,4) $.

Answer (score 1):

Your plane is a two dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the orthogonal compliment is a one dimensional object in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  We are looking for a subspace such that each vector in the plane is orthogonal to every vector in the orthogonal compliment.

*Do you know of any structure associated with planes that is orthogonal to vectors in a plane?*

Scroll over for the answer:

> The Normal Vector